# mySQL Range of values between years

Tags: mysql, range, between

I'm quite new to SQL in this form. So I apologize if this is an obvious/stupid question.

Basically I am writing a simple query that should look up the King of Wessex within a year range. The years are stored as INT because I don't think it could handle years that go below 1000AD. Anyway.

The user should enter the year range they are interested in, for example, 793 - 794. This is entered in a form with two text boxes.

Beorhtric would be the King of Wessex at the time reigning from 786 to 802, but using the current BETWEEN function that only brings back the event of Lindisfarne Abbey being torched by the Vikings. What I would also want returned is that Beorhtric is the King of Wessex at this time.

Here is my code thus far:

```
<?php

  $con = mysql_connect("");
  if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("magorumc_authentibase", $con);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM exportinfomod
           WHERE date_s BETWEEN ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchs'])." 
                 AND ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['searchd'])." 
           ORDER BY date_s ASC");
  echo "<b>Output Display in Table formate and php formate</b><br>";
  echo "<table border='1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Start Date</th>
  <th>End Date</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Text</th>
  </tr>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date_s'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date_e'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['text'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Alex

Comment: You should not be using `mysql_query` in new applications. This interface is antiquated, dangerous, and will be removed in future versions of PHP. To make your code future-proof, you should be using something like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). While it's good that you're calling `mysql_real_escape_string` on every single variable, using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is significantly easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing the correct logic here for this to work as you expect. This is a typical problem with ranges as they can be considerably less than intuitive.

For instance, if event A spanned time t=2 through t=6 and you want to know what events were going on between t=4 and t=5, you won't find A unless you get your ranges right.

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT ... WHERE date_s <= :searchd AND date_e >= :searchs
```

This presumes `:searchd` to be the end of your range, and `:searchs` to be the start. In long form this means "Find all events where the event started *before* the end of the range and ended *after* the start of the range." I believe this would work, as in the contrived example, `6 >= 5` and `2 <= 4` so that event would qualify.